# How do I run a gradlew build using native Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradlew

I can build an Android Studio project manually (in the editor) but when trying to use the gradlew.bat file to build the same project, it can't find JAVA_HOME.

I don't have Java installed - Android Studio uses a built in version of Java which the command line build should be able to use as well.

How do I set this up?

Everything is up to date (latest Studio & latest gradle version for the project)

I've tried `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\jre64\bin` & without `\bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This path did the trick: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`